# JNDI naming exception on JRE7

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, naming

We are facing a problem , we have code base compiled in JDK 6. Now we are migrating to JRE-7, which eventually means we are running code compiled in JDK-6 with JRE -7. Everything is working fine apart from JNDI. We are getting following exception:

```
2015-05-25 09:44:41,769 ERROR ne.LdapNeNotifListener - NamingExceptionEvent recieved from ABC:
javax.naming.NamingException: LDAP response read timed out, timeout used:-1ms.
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Connection.java:483)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getSearchReply(LdapClient.java:639)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getSearchReply(LdapClient.java:607)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.getSearchReply(LdapCtx.java:1919)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:129)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreImpl(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:216)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.hasMore(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:189)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.NamingEventNotifier.run(NamingEventNotifier.java:134)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As we can see that timeout is -1 hence infinite according to JAVA docs.
What is causing the problem here?

Comment: Are you setting [`com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap.html#PROP) anywhere? If so, to what?

Comment: No, I did not default is infinite according to Docs

Comment: How long does it take to time out?

Comment: 10 seconds approximate.

Comment: Code is working fine if i run the code with jre 6

Comment: I know this is not really a valid answer, but I had the same problem and in order to fix it I'm just setting the timeout manually to the server's timeout...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just downloaded and tested JRE version 7u80.

Everything is working fine here. I did not see any exception.

It is JRE version below or equal 7u79 that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this issue? Oracle says fixed in 7 update 91, but I can't tell for sure. Resolution date and other backports made around the same time as your report.
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8081560